# Is it possible to automatically create automapper mappings?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

Maybe this is a stupid question, but it's really not obvious for me :(

```
var address = new Address { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe" };

// Configure AutoMapper
Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>();

// Perform mapping
var viewModel = Mapper.Map<Address, AddressViewModel>(address);
```

Imho `Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>();` is not needed, because AutoMapper gets this information afterwards where the mapping is performed.

So why do I have to write those configurations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a quick [browse through the source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/MappingEngine.cs), it appears that it stores it's mappings in the engine so that any calls that follow load the mapping data from the engine.

This is probably due to the fact that reflection can be expensive and there's no way for the AutoMapper to know how few - or many - times someone will use just Mapper.Map. Definition: caching :)

Comment: I'd think you would want do define your maps in global asap or app_start as well wouldn't you?

Comment: Oh, that too. I just assumed the OP's code was an example, not actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally this pattern is very useful for validating that your configuration is correct (see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation). Some mappings require fairly specific configuration, and this catches any errors early.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, Automapper doesn't necessarily get all of this information when the mapping is performed, because you may have specified any number of .ForMember / .AfterMap (etc) chainings in your CreateMap expression. You don't want to have to repeat all of that in every mapping invocation.